# Is it possible to show ipynb file in Opengrok?

Tags: opengrok, ipynb

I want to show the ipynb file to Opengrok Service, but the ipynb file shows XML or JSON format. This is not readable.

Is there a method to show ipynb file in a readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OpenGrok doesn´t have a method to render and show the ipynb files formatted.